# Mockito not working when method start Observable

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, retrofit

im trying to test a presenter, but the test only pass when things are outside of Observable, my presenter:

```
class CompManCodePresenter @Inject constructor(val apiBag: ServiceModule.ApiBag, disposable: CompositeDisposable, scheduler: SchedulerProvider) : BasePresenter<CompManCodeView>(disposable, scheduler) {

    fun validateCompmanCode(code: String) {
        view?.showProgress()
        if (code.isEmpty()) {
            view?.emptyCode()
            view?.hideProgress()
        } else {

            val request = mutableMapOf<String, Any?>()
            request.put("code", code)
            disposable.add(
                    apiBag.apiMainFast.check_code(JWT.jwt_encrypted(request))
                    .subscribeOn(scheduler.io())
                    .observeOn(scheduler.ui())
                    .subscribe(
                            { result ->
                                view?.hideProgress()
                            },
                            { error ->
                                view?.hideProgress()
                                view?.onError()
                            })
            )
        }

    }
```

rest api part:

```
@POST("v2/check-code")
fun check_code(@Body body: JwtDataRequest): Observable<SyncCompManAndDeviceResponse>
```

test that works ok:

```
@Test
fun test_code_empty() {
    val mockedResponse: Throwable = mock()
    val params = HashMap<String, Any>()
    val mockedRequest = JWT.jwt_encrypted(params)

    doReturn(Observable.just(mockedResponse)).`when`(api).check_code(mockedRequest)
    presenter.validateCompmanCode("")

    testScheduler.triggerActions()

    verify(view).showProgress()
    verify(view).emptyCode()
    verify(view).hideProgress()
}
```

**test that is not working (it only run the .showProgress outside**

```
 @Test
    fun test_no_connection() {

        val mockedResponse: Throwable = mock()
        val params = HashMap<String, Any>()
        val mockedRequest = JWT.jwt_encrypted(params)

        doReturn(Observable.just(mockedResponse)).`when`(api).check_code(mockedRequest)
        presenter.validateCompmanCode("A")

        testScheduler.triggerActions()
        verify(view).showProgress()
        verify(view).hideProgress()
        verify(view).onError()
    }
```

my test class setup:

```
  private val view: CompManCodeView = mock()
    private lateinit var presenter: CompManCodePresenter
    private lateinit var testScheduler: TestScheduler

    val api:RestAPI = Mockito.mock(RestAPI::class.java, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    val apiBag:ServiceModule.ApiBag = Mockito.spy(ServiceModule.ApiBag(api,api,api,api))



    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
        testScheduler = TestScheduler()
        val testSchedulerProvider = TestSchedulerProvider(testScheduler)
        presenter = CompManCodePresenter(apiBag, disposable = compositeDisposable, scheduler = testSchedulerProvider)
        presenter.attachView(view)
    }
```

no error show, the only thing that the test result show is this:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
view.hideProgress();


However, there were exactly 2 interactions with this mock:
view.setPresenter(
    CompManCodePresenter@72ee5d84
);
-> BasePresenter.attachView(BasePresenter.kt:13)

view.showProgress();
-> at CompManCodePresenter.validateCompmanCode(CompManCodePresenter.kt:21)
```

im following this: https://github.com/burakeregar/KotlinRxMvpArchitecture

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer, i dont know why, i tested this before, but was throwing a error about object not being a mock, but i tested again and worked:

change

```
val api:RestAPI = Mockito.mock(RestAPI::class.java, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
```

to

```
val api:RestAPI = Mockito.spy(MockRetrofitApi.mockApi())
```

mockApi only return a `new Retrofit.create(RestApi.class)`